# Simulate Different Key Combinations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to simulate different key combinations, such as ctrl+a, ctrl+s ctrl+alt+delete and bind them on a div in the interface.

As I understand it, I have to create my own events and call them in a method, that will work when I click on this div.

**How can I call few events at the same time or is there another way?**

Comment: Lack in details, put your code.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You do not call the events, but rather register event handlers. And you can register as many event handlers as you like. First you need to look at the types of [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) that can be used. Among those you will notice the [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown), the [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) and the [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) events. Now that you know what events you can work with when it comes to key events. Then study [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), see a few examples of its usage. When you have done all of this, you are ready to start planning your own assignment. You will know that you will be able to solve all the key combinations using a single event handler, since it will catch your events and you will be able to check the combinations. To be able to solve your own combinations, study some [earlier works](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keyboard_ctrl_alt_shift.htm).

Comment: I can put any event in main events stream through dispatchEvent() method. Did you know that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent